# Why does this simple getInteger function cause a stream failure?

Tags: c++, macos

I've been working with the StanfordCPPLib working through Eric S. Roberts' "Programming Abstractions in C++" but this function in the simpio.h is suddenly giving me grief. It worked fine in the past but as it stands now no matter what number/letter/etc I enter it gives me the "Illegal integer format. Try again."

I tried some debugging by removing the !stream.fail() bit from the if statement and it works like a charm... but part of the whole point in using this function is checking that fail state.  Hmmm.

The only relevant thing I can recall doing since using this library last was upgrading to OSX 10.9 from 10.8

What am I missing?  Thanks in advance!

```
 /*
 * Implementation notes: getInteger, getReal
 * -----------------------------------------
 * Each of these functions reads a complete input line and then uses the
 * <sstream> library to parse that line into a value of the desired type.
 * If that fails, the implementation asks the user for a new value.
 */

int getInteger(string prompt) {
   int value;
   string line;
   while (true) {
      cout << prompt;
      getline(cin, line);
      istringstream stream(line);
      stream >> value >> ws;
      if (!stream.fail() && stream.eof()) break;
      cout << "Illegal integer format. Try again." << endl;
      if (prompt == "") prompt = "Enter an integer: ";
   }
   return value;
}
```

Comment: It works here too : https://ideone.com/Lki2dG

Comment: [Reproduced](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DeTYVed7C8QLQGYX) with clang/libc++.

Comment: The difference appears to be that in libc++, `stream >> ws` when the stream's `eofbit` is set also sets `failbit`.

Comment: Thank you T.C. for your explanation and workaround idea!  It did the trick. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a string `"123"` extracted by `getline` and then put into the `istringstream`.

`stream >> value` will extract `123`, and set `eofbit` on the stream.

Then `stream >> ws` happens. `ws` is specified to first construct a `sentry` object, whose constructor is specified to call `is.setstate(failbit)` if `is.good()` is `false` - which it is, as `eofbit` is set. As a result, `stream.fail()` is `true` and `!stream.fail() && stream.eof()` is `false`, and your code prints "Illegal integer format".

libstdc++'s implementation doesn't set `failbit` in this case, which appears nonconforming.

A simple workaround is to add a trailing space at the end of `line`:

```
  istringstream stream(line + " ");
```

This ensures that `ws` will always be called without `eofbit` set, so that the constructor of `sentry` won't set `failbit`.